# Ambiguous call between overloads of two-way implicit castable types when a derived type of one is passed as parameter

Tags: c#, overloading, ambiguous, implicit-conversion

(Trying to find a title that sums up a problem can be a very daunting task!)

I have the following classes with some overloaded methods that produce a call ambiguity compiler error:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void OverloadedMethod(MyClass l) { }
    public static void OverloadedMethod(MyCastableClass l) { }

    //Try commenting this out separately from the next implicit operator. 
    //Comment out the resulting offending casts in Test() as well.
    public static implicit operator MyCastableClass(MyClass l)
    {
        return new MyCastableClass();
    }

    //Try commenting this out separately from the previous implicit operator.
    //Comment out the resulting offending casts in Test() as well.
    public static implicit operator MyClass(MyCastableClass l)
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }

    static void Test()
    {
        MyDerivedClass derived = new MyDerivedClass();
        MyClass class1 = new MyClass();
        MyClass class2 = new MyDerivedClass();
        MyClass class3 = new MyCastableClass();
        MyCastableClass castableClass1 = new MyCastableClass();
        MyCastableClass castableClass2 = new MyClass();
        MyCastableClass castableClass3 = new MyDerivedClass();

        OverloadedMethod(derived); //Ambiguous call between OverloadedMethod(MyClass l) and OverloadedMethod(MyCastableClass l)
        OverloadedMethod(class1);
        OverloadedMethod(class2);
        OverloadedMethod(class3);
        OverloadedMethod(castableClass1);
        OverloadedMethod(castableClass2);
        OverloadedMethod(castableClass3);

    }

public class MyDerivedClass : MyClass {  }

public class MyCastableClass { }
```

There are two very interesting things to note:

1. Commenting out any of the implicit operator methods removes the ambiguity.
2. Trying to rename the first method overload in VS will rename the first four calls in the Test() method!

This naturally poses two questions:

1. What it the logic behind the compiler error (i.e. how did the compiler arrive to an ambiguity)?
2. Is there anything wrong with this design? Intuitively there should be no ambiguity and the offending call should be resolved in the first method overload (`OverloadedMethod(MyClass l, MyClass r)`) as `MyDerivedClass` is more closely related to `MyClass` rather than the castable but otherwise irrelevant `MyCastableClass`. Furthermore VS refactoring seems to agree with this intuition.

**EDIT:**
After playing around with VS refactoring, I saw that VS matches the offending method call with the first overload that is defined in code whichever that is. So if we interchange the two overloads VS matches the offending call to the one with the `MyCastableClass` parameter. The questions are still valid though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What it the logic behind the compiler error (i.e. how did the compiler arrive to an ambiguity)?

First we must determine what methods are in the *method group*.  Clearly there are two methods in the method group.

Second, we must determine which of those two methods are *applicable*. That is, every argument is convertible implicitly to the corresponding parameter type. Clearly both methods are applicable.

Third, given that there is more than one applicable method, a *unique best* method must be determined. In the case where there are only two methods each with only one parameter, the rule is that the *conversion* from the *argument* to the *parameter type* of one must be *better* than to the other.

The rules for what makes one conversion better than another is in section 7.5.3.5 of the specification, which I quote here for your convenience:

> Given a conversion C1 that converts from a type S to a type T1, and a conversion C2 that converts from a type S to a type T2, C1 is a better conversion than C2 if at least one of the following holds:
>
> • An identity conversion exists from S to T1 but not from S to T2
>
> • T1 is a better conversion target than T2
>
> Given two different types T1 and T2, T1 is a better conversion target than T2 if at least one of the following holds:
>
> • An implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists, and no implicit conversion from T2 to T1 exists

The purpose of this rule is to determine which type is *more specific*. If every Banana is a Fruit but not every Fruit is a Banana, then Banana is more specific than Fruit.

> • T1 is a signed integral type and T2 is an unsigned integral type.

Run down the list. Is there an **identity** conversion from `MyDerivedClass` to either `MyCastableClass` or `MyClass`?  No.  Is there an implicit conversion from `MyClass` to `MyCastableClass` but **not** an implicit conversion going the other way?  No. There is no reason to suppose that either type is more specific than the other. Are either integral types?  No.

Therefore there is nothing upon which to base the decision that one is better than the other, and therefore this is ambiguous.

> Is there anything wrong with this design?

The question answers itself. You've found one of the problems.

> Intuitively there should be no ambiguity and the offending call should be resolved in the first method overload as MyDerivedClass is more closely related to MyClass

Though that might be intuitive to you, the spec does not make a distinction *in this case* between a user-defined conversion and any other implicit conversion. However I note that your distiction *does* count in some rare cases; see my article for details. ([Chained user-defined explicit conversions in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/chained-user-defined-explicit-conversions-in-c))

Comment: Eric, elaborating more on the fruit example consider this: Firstly there is a meaningful implicit conversion between `Fruit` and `FruitJam`. Then we also have two overloads: `Consume(Fruit)` and `Consume(FruitJam)`. The first performs (amongst other things) a `PeelFruit` action while the second an `OpenBottle` action (i.e. they do different things). Isn’t it clear which method the `Consume(Banana)` should resolve to? I see that according to the spec the compiler does not distinguish between user-defined implicit conversions and generalization (Banana->Fruit) but should that have been the case?

Comment: @GDS: You're now asking the moral question "the product does not work the way I would have designed it; is the product wrong?" Well, any time the product doesn't work the way a user thinks it should, *something* went wrong in either the design or the user education process. But the product is the way it is, and changing it would be a dangerous breaking change that would cause more trouble than it produced benefits.

Comment: I am not trying to be critical of the product. I am pretty sure that there are a million considerations from the designers’ team that I wouldn’t even begin to comprehend. I am just trying to see if there is something conceptually wrong in my thinking/design which is a core issue in a project that I am developing and is very closely related to this unanswered question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624878/how-to-overload-an-operator-of-a-generic-class-with-operands-of-different-generi). If conceptually my design is not wrong but there is a limitation in the product then...

Comment: ...I could try to find ways around it. But if my design is wrong I need to correct it now before it might be too late in the developing process. (PS I am self-taught which is the reason I am seeking confirmation for my design).

Comment: @EricLippert: Perhaps what GDS might be trying to ask is: if you could start from a clean slate, would you still design method overload resolution this way or would you do it differently, and why?

Comment: @EricLippert: don't forget to upvote every now and then - at least on Christmas ;) (a question worth answering is a question worth upvoting, right?) (http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6856/high-standards-top-100-users-that-rarely-upvote)

Comment: @Raffael: I add value in other ways. Since I have answered hundreds of questions and upvoted none of them, clearly I do not agree with your hypothesis about value.

Comment: @EricLippert: to each his own - though, given your numerous downvotes your concept of valuation may not claim the intellectual virtue of symmetry :)

Comment: @Raffael: My downvotes are a vanishingly small percentage of the literally hundreds of thousands of questions and answers I've reviewed on this site, and are limited to those that are actively harming the internet.  Is the way you add value to this site by criticizing the choices of others who give up their spare time to help others?

Comment: @EricLippert: Raffael did not intend to critisize you - he is just dabbling in armchair psychological profiling and enjoys asking irritating questions ;)

Answer (score 3):

> What it the logic behind the compiler error?

Well, the compiler determines the signature based on a few things. The number and type of the parameters is next to the name, one of the most important ones. The compiler checks if a method call is ambiguous. It doesn't only use the actual type of the parameter, but also the types it can be *implicitly* casted to (note that explicit casts are out of the picture, they are not used here).

This gives the issue you describe.

> Is there anything wrong with this design?

Yes. Ambiguous methods are a source of a lot of problems. Especially when using variable types, like `dynamic`. Even in this case, the compiler can't choose which method to call, and that is bad. We want software to be deterministic, and with this code, it can't be.

You didn't ask for it, but I guess the best option is:

1. To rethink your design. Do you really need the `implicit` casts? If so, why do you need two methods instead of one?
2. Use `explicit` casting instead of `implicit` casting, to make casting a deliberate choice a compiler can understand.

Comment: This answers neither of the questions but your point of whether both overloads are needed was interesting. Unfortunately in my case both the implicit casts and the overloads are meaningful, valid and I believe essential, even if your point made me code the overloads more effectively.

Comment: Why do you think my answer doesn't answer the questions? If `A=B` and `B=A`, what should the compiler choose when having a signature for `A` and `B`?

Comment: Assuming that `A` is the original class, `B` is the castable class and `C` is the derived class, `A` is NOT equal to `B`, it is merely equivalent to or substitutable for `B` (and vice versa). On the other hand `C` IS an `A`. Conceptually there should have been a preference to call the `A` overload over the `B` overload, in the same way the `A` overload is chosen when the parameter is of type `A` (which is trivial). The reason I said you did not answer that part of the question is because there is no explanation of why the compiler considers it an ambiguity when IMO it should not have been one.