# Two extension methods with ambiguous signature

Tags: c#, overloading

```
public static string AddRange(this List<Parameter> parameters, string name, object[] values)
{
    ...
}

public static string AddRange(this List<Parameter> parameters, string name, IEnumerable<object> values)
{
    return parameters.AddRange(name, values.ToArray());
}
```

This combination, when called like this:

```
SomeFunction(params string[] keys)
{
    ...
    parameters.AddRange("paramKeys", keys);
    ...
}
```

throws

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ExtensionMethods.AddRange(List, string, object[])' and 'ExtensionMethods.AddRange(List, string, IEnumerable)'

I know roughly why this is thrown (an Array also is an IEnumerable), but I don't know how to fix it without removing any of the two methods. How can I tell the `IEnumerable<object>` method that it is not responsible for arrays, but for all other kinds of `IEnumerable<object>`?

Comment: Why do you have two overloads in the first place?

Comment: You can just cast to the one you want `parameters.AddRange("paramKeys", (object[])keys)`

Comment: I am not getting any compilation error with Visual Studio 2015. Is it due to C# 6.0's [Improved overload resolution](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6)?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606199/ambiguous-call-between-overloads-of-two-way-implicit-castable-types-when-a-deriv and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451099/how-to-override-an-existing-extension-method for useful discussion of overload resolution in general, as it applies to these types of ambiguous scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the problem because a `string[]` is type of `IEnumerable` but also is the type of an `object[]` (Since all reference types derive from `object`).

What you need to do is cast it to the correct type that the extension method is expecting:

```
parameters.AddRange("paramKeys", (object[])keys);
// OR
parameters.AddRange("paramKeys", (IEnumerable<object>)keys);
```